# Raspberry Pi Zero W losing WiFi-Connection after AccessPoint restart

Tags: wifi, connection

I have noticed, that raspberry Pi’s are predictable in losing their Wifi-Connection permanently  after the accesspoint was turned off (power off).
I have tried multiple raspberrys (10+) and three different vendors of accesspoints and was able to monitor the following behaviour:

Raspberry Pi is losing connection to the accesspoint for an about 40% chance and cannot reestablish it. In an about 60% chance, the connection is reestablished automatically after the ap is powered on again.
This means, that usually after 3-4 AP reboots, the connection is not alive on all tested raspis.

Environment

- Raspberry Pi Zero W with Raspbian Jessie
- WIFI-Country set to DE
- Test scenario: AP is restarted every hour by timed switch. Stays of for 5 Minutes and is than powered on again.

Syslog-Output, when raspi is able to re-establish the connection (60% chance)

[image: syslog-output]

Syslog-Output, when raspi is NOT able  to re-establish the connection (40% chance)

[image: syslog-output2]

I think: It seems that `dhcpcd` does not realize that there is no `physical wireless` connection. An `acquired` is not even executed. Only a reboot or a restart of the network-stack solves the problem.

Ifconfig – Output (when NOT able to reestablish)

[image: ifconfig-output]

Iwconfig – Output (when NOT able to reestablish)

[image: iwconfig-output]

Wpa_cli status (when NOT able to reestablish)

[image: wpa-cli-output]

systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service (when NOT able to reestablish)

[image: systemctl-output]

I appreciate any help or ideas, that help me to point into the right direction to find the cause of the problem.

Thank you

Comment: please post text as text, not as a fuzzy screenshot ... use the `edit` button to update your post

Comment: Have you tried putting your configuration particulars under an `interface wlan0` line in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`?